# Different font rendering on subpages with the same styling on webkit browsers on Mac OS X

Tags: css, macos, fonts, webkit

I'm working on a website, and I have a problem with displaying font on two subages in webkit browsers on Mac OS X. In all Windows browsers fonts look the same.

In Safari and Chrome on Mac the font on http://clients.cateristic.com/2013/catering/hospitality/vip-catering-fur-mcarthurglen-group/ is bolder than on http://clients.cateristic.com/2013/portfolio/hospitality-catering-texas-usa/ even though the styling of `.project-description` and `.single-container` are the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... maybe set a particular numeric font weight for the classes? 
for example instead of font-weight: normal, set font weight: 400. Perhaps the browsers have different interpretations of font-weights.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/fonts/qt/aa031807.htm